# can c# be used for communicating mobile and pc?

Tags: c#, mobile

As a minor project in my degree I would like to communicate mobile and pc .I am interested to communicate through bluetooth is it possible to do so in c#?
If possible please provide me list of application or hardware i would requiere in order to do so.

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to better define "Mobile".  Windows Mobile?  Some other phone?  Some PDA?

Answer (score 1):

If (and it's a big if based on the lack of information in your question) you mean "How do I write an app on my PC, using C#, that can communicate with a [Windows Mobile](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/default.mspx) device that is connected to my PC via [ActiveSync](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/activesync45.mspx) or [WMDC](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/device-center.mspx)" then the answer is [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458022.aspx).  A free, open-source managed wrapper for it [is here](http://opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/DesktopCommunication/tabid/90/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible if its with windows mobile phone or pocket pc with bluetooth. You need a bluetooth enabled computer and mobile phone. For dev you need to  download the [windows mobile 6 sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en).

Then developing of the communication between desktop app and mobile phone app, you can use the [32feet.Net](http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx) is open source.

When you download it and installs (well it unpacks to program files folder) you will have the dll that you make reference to in Visual Studio. Also you will get some sample apps. One of them is a Bluetooth Chat that works in Desktop, Pocket PC and SmartPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you could use is set up a web service that acts like an intermediary between the device and your machine. One huge benefit of this is that no longer are you bound by the distance requirements of bluetooth.

Of course if you're trying to build some sort of proximity service (do z when item x is 3 meters from item y) then bluetooth is probably the way to go.